# Pagination with Microsoft sql & PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

Trying to do some pageintaion with mssql & php but i cant seem to get it working... i get no errors, so i cant really find out what im doing wrong, am i missing anything obvious?

```
 <?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 $dbhost = 'localhost';
 $dbuser = '*****';
$dbpass = '******';
$db = 'blog';
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$dbuser,                            
"PWD"=>$dbpass,                            
"Database"=>$db, "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"); 
$connect_db = sqlsrv_connect ( $dbhost, $connectionInfo ) or die(sqlsrv_errors());

if ((!isset($_GET['pagenum'])) || (!is_numeric($_GET['pagenum'])) || ($_GET['pagenum'] < 1)) { $pagenum = 1; }
else { $pagenum = $_GET['pagenum']; }

$result = sqlsrv_query ($connect_db,"SELECT blogID FROM blog_posts") or die(sqlsrv_errors());

$rows = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);

$page_rows = 2; 

$last = ceil($rows/$page_rows); 
if (($pagenum > $last) && ($last > 0)) { $pagenum = $last; }

$max = ($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows;

$result2 = sqlsrv_query(($connect_db,"SELECT TOP $page_rows FROM blog_posts WHERE blogID NOT IN (SELECT TOP $max blogID FROM blog_posts ORDER BY blogID ASC) ORDER BY blogID ASC") or die(sqlsrv_errors()); 

while($info = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result2, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH )) 
{ 
    print $info['blogID']; 
    echo "<br>";
} 
echo "<p>";
echo " --Page $pagenum of $last-- <p>";

if ($pagenum == 1) { } 
    else 
    {
        echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=1'> <<-First</a> ";
        echo " ";
        $previous = $pagenum-1;
        echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$previous'> <-Previous</a> ";
    } 
    echo " ---- ";
    if ($pagenum == $last) 
    {
    } 
    else {
        $next = $pagenum+1;
        echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$next'>Next -></a> ";
        echo " ";
        echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$last'>Last ->></a> ";
    } 
    ?>
```

blogID is the unique id of every post in the db

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: You've asked for "top $max" .. not from end of previous page to end of current page.. and your first page has pagenum of 1, which you subtract 1 and * pagerows.. so, thats 0 items for page 1, 2 for page 2, 4 for page 3...

Comment: @noa-dev i just get a blank page basically so i dont know exactly what isnt working... :)

Comment: @BugFinder uh okey how do i correct this the easiest way? kinda tried it all it feels like

Comment: Its all a matter of logic - I had hoped you would see my explaination of why you get 0 items for page 1 etc and have a clue how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non technical answer (eg, not writing all your code for you)

You've currently got the code that says `$max = (page number-1) * length of page`

-if page = 1, then max = 0, so there is no data for page 1

-for page 2, you'd have 1 page length of stuff

-for page 3, you'd have 2 page lengths of stuff

clearly - this isnt what you meant. What you meant to do was select the number of rows from end of previous page, to the end of the current page. MSSQL is less good at this

firstly

you need a min and max. to show from

`$min = (page number -1 * pagelength)+1`
(eg not the same record at end of one page and the beginning of the next)
`$max = page number * pagelength`

if page length was 5, a page view might be min record 21, and max 25

you can then use SQL like
`SELECT  *
FROM    ( <your query here>
        ) AS RowConstrainedResult
WHERE   RowNum >= $min
    AND RowNum < $max
ORDER BY RowNum`

your current select statement only gets a blog id - so its going to be a rather boring page but.. thats your call - but hopefully you get the idea.

You would also need to know the number of records, as you'd need to decide if there are more pages after all.

Comment: thanks for clarifying abit :) yea i know it only gets the id, i just want it to work and after that i will add the rest of the stuff :)

Comment: You should be able to fix your code with that. it is mostly done for you